# File Renamer Regular expression to Remove Repeated string

Tags: regex, capture, replace, file-rename

I Have FOLDER names like these examples

```
sons.of.anarchy.s05e01.hdtv.x264-2hd.nfo - sons.of.anarchy.s05e01.hdtv.x264-2hd.
sons.of.anarchy.s05e03.hdtv.x264-asap.nfo - sons.of.anarchy.s05e03.hdtv.x264-asap.
Jump.3.training.Or.Wand.3410.7200k.Blade.DD.5.1.x300-NTb - Jump.3.training.Or.Wand.3410.7200k.Blade.DD.5.1.x300-NTb.
```

And similar FILE names like these samples

```
sons.of.anarchy.s05e01.hdtv.x264-2hd.nfo - sons.of.anarchy.s05e01.hdtv.x264-2hd.mp4
Jump.3.training.Or.Wand.3410.7200k.Blade.DD.5.1.x300-NTb - Jump.3.training.Or.Wand.3410.7200k.Blade.DD.5.1.x300-NTb.avi
```

I want to build a RegEx that will rename the files/folders with the repeated string removed.

Folders Like this:

```
sons.of.anarchy.s05e01.hdtv.x264-2hd
sons.of.anarchy.s05e03.hdtv.x264-asap
Jump.3.training.Or.Wand.3410.7200k.Blade.DD.5.1.x300-NTb
```

Files like this

```
sons.of.anarchy.s05e01.hdtv.x264-2hd.mp4
Jump.3.training.Or.Wand.3410.7200k.Blade.DD.5.1.x300-NTb.avi
```

Ultimately I'm Aiming for the names to look like this:

```
Sons Of Anarchy S05E01
Sons Of Anarchy S05E03
Jump 3 Training Or Wand
Sons Of Anarchy S05E01.mp4
Jump 3 Training Or Wand.avi
```

I use custom Expressions to remove specific strings, periods & hyphens And it takes several steps.
Here are a few expressions I use to clean names up in Renamer:

```
Find: [\.\-_/~\[\])("] and I replace with a space

Find: \s*$ and I replace with nothing to Remove spaces at the end of Names
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you make more clear what is the question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using regex pattern

```
^(.*?)([.]\w*|)\s+[-]\s+\1([.](?=$))?([.]\w*|)$
```

with replacement of

```
$1$4
```

See this **[Perl demo](http://ideone.com/bCeHyW)**.

---

To learn more about regular expressions, visit [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).